# php where query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP and my requirement is to check the user email id in database and if exists ,  navigate to next page. But by SQL query is not working in PHP , and working in SQL database.

My database structure :

[image]

My HTML Code : index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="checkform.php" method="post">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

PHP: checkform.php

```
<?php
try 
{
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
mysql_select_db("mobileblog", $connection);  
$emailid = $_POST['email']; 
echo $emailid;
$sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email=" . $_POST['email'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $result;
if(!$result) { echo "<p class='error'>Error: No such email address</p>"; }
// note that the if is asking if there is no result
else {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo "<p class='success'>Welcome " . $row['Name'] . "!!</p>";
}
} // end

//mysql_query(" // suggest here to validate against emails in db");
mysql_close($connection);
echo "SUCCESS";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
// Note: Log the error or something
}
?>
```

My page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to Page 2</h1>
</body> 
</html>
```

But when running the index.html page , facing the error: (which eventually does nt execute the mysql query),But running the sql query is successful

```
Error: No such email address
SUCCESS
```

PHP Query (failed)

```
$sql = "SELECT `Name` FROM `table` WHERE email=\'jxxx@gmail.com\'";
```

SQL Query (Success)

```
SELECT `Name` FROM `table` WHERE email='jxxx@gmail.com'
```

Why does it fail to run the query ?

Comment: `WHERE email= '".$emailid."'`

Comment: Post that as an answer!

Comment: I would recommend into learning PDO MYSQL because the method you are using now is the old way. Here you have a nice tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: additional short comment to WHY it is failing: you used `"` as string delimiter, but tried to escape the `'`s. But the single quote has no special meaning in a double quoted string, so an escape is not necessary, so the php interpreter treated `\'` as a string (two characters): the sql server got a request with `...email=\'jx...\'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested by John:

use quotes

```
WHERE email= '".$emailid."'
```

---

```
$emailid = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$emailid = mysql_real_escape_string($emailid);
$sql = "SELECT `Name` from `table` WHERE `email`= '".$emailid."'";
```

in conjunction with `$emailid = $_POST['email'];`

instead of

```
WHERE email=" . $_POST['email']
```

which would both cause an error and is open to SQL injection in using that method.

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're safer*.

---

***Sidenote:***

If your table name is indeed called `table`, wrap it in backticks (just an insight).

```
$sql = "SELECT Name from `table`...
```

- **It's a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

---

**Edit:** rewrite

```
<?php
try 
{
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
mysql_select_db("mobileblog", $connection);  
$emailid = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$emailid = mysql_real_escape_string($emailid); 
echo $emailid;
$sql = "SELECT `Name` from `table` WHERE `email`= '".$emailid."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $result;
if(!$result) { echo "<p class='error'>Error: No such email address</p>"; }
// note that the if is asking if there is no result
else {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo "<p class='success'>Welcome " . $row['Name'] . "!!</p>";
}
} // end

//mysql_query(" // suggest here to validate against emails in db");
mysql_close($connection);
echo "SUCCESS";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
// Note: Log the error or something
}
?>
```

---

**Edit #2** (helping out)

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
mysql_select_db("mobileblog", $connection);  
$emailid = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$emailid = mysql_real_escape_string($emailid); 
$sql = "SELECT `Name` from `table` WHERE `email`= '".$emailid."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//  if($result) {
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
header("Location: page2.php");
exit;
}

else {

echo "<p class='error'>Error: No such email address</p>"; 

} // brace for else

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: A better answer than mine.

Comment: using  WHERE email= '".$emailid."' results with  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\checkform.php on line 11

Comment: @user3592479 My answer does not contain `using WHERE email=" . $_POST['email']` - it reads as `WHERE email= '".$emailid."'`

Comment: edited .  changing to WHERE email= '".$emailid."' results with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\checkform.php on line 11

Comment: @user3592479 what exactly are you entering in the form field?

Comment: @user3592479 and reload my answer. I've made a few modifications in adding `stripslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @user3592479 edit is `$emailid = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$emailid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$sql = "SELECT `Name` from `table` WHERE `email`= '".$emailid."'";` - reload the answer.

Comment: @user3592479 did you reload my answer and tried it? That should work.

Comment: i am confused , please let me know which part of code is to be replaced with your code ?

Comment: @user3592479 Reload and look at the bottom under **Edit: rewrite**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60622/discussion-between-user3592479-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 3):

Can you try it? It may concatenation issue

```
$sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email=" . $_POST['email'];
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email='". $_POST['email']."'";
```

Its also getting failure due to single quotes inside POST

Have to do create variable and cal for the safe like fred post

```
$email=$_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email='". $email."'";
```

or we can do something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']))."'";
```

Comment: my current query $sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email='". $_POST['email']."'"; also fails

Comment: can you try it? 
    $sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email='".  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'"; updated in my post

Comment: using $sql = "SELECT Name from 'table' WHERE email='". $email."'"; throws  Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\checkform.php on line 8 and $sql = "SELECT Name from table WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'"; results    Error: No such email address

Comment: Undefined variable: email means you want to declare this line $email=$_POST['email']; before this line  $sql = "SELECT Name from 'table' WHERE email='". $email."'";

Comment: Error: No such email address Is this server error? or your custom error?

Comment: No such email address is a custom error  from  echo $result;
if(!$result) { echo "<p class='error'>Error: No such email address</p>"; }

Comment: Then result is empty. you posted email is in sql?

Comment: yes it is . my default question also throws the same error . It contains the email in the database

Comment: did u tried '".stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']))."'"   ?

Comment: you just echo this.. echo mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'];

Comment: can you check.. Its working for me email='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']))."'";

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simply:

```
$emailid = $_POST['email'];
// or beter: $emailid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$sql = "SELECT `Name` FROM `table` WHERE email='$emailid'";
```

Function mysql_real_escape_string() is for safe use $emailid.